# Proving that if $0<r<1$ and $x_{n} \rightarrow r$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $(x_{n})^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I am trying to prove the following statement:

If $0<r<1$ and $x_{n} \rightarrow r$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $(x_{n})^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I'm really stuck with this at the moment. I have seen many examples where $x_{n}$ is defined in terms of n, but I do not understand how to link these statements together.

I understand that we need to link the statement $|x_{n}-r|<\epsilon_{1}$ for $n>N_{1}$ to the statement $|(x_{n})^n|<\epsilon_{2}$ for $n>N_{2}$ but haven't managed to do it.

Can anyone solve this or outline a general way of solving similar questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large values of $n$, you have that $0<x_n<c$ where $c$ is some fixed number such that $r<c<1$ (for example, $c=r + \frac{1-r}{2} = \frac{1+r}2$, i.e. the halfway point between $r$ and $1$).

Then,

$$0<x_n^n < c^n$$

and then use the squeeze principle.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$0<x_n<\frac{r+1}2$ for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $\varepsilon<1-r$ where $1-r>0$ then $\varepsilon+r<1$ so $(\varepsilon+r)^n\to0$.